# Trapped in cave with no golden claw

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I forgot to get the golden claw from arvel and as I continued, rocks fell behind me how do I get the golden claw

Comment: Are you on PC or Console?

Comment: Do you have an autosave from before that happened?

Comment: Just reviewed the game and at no point between Arvel and the door that requires the key are there any rocks that fall to block your path.

Answer (score 10):

As @Ben stated this logic does not happen in this dungeon. It is a ruins however so there are places that look collapsed but they do not hinder your movement through the dungeon forward or backward, they are just decor.

Utilize your map, you should be able to follow it back to where the golden claw is. If you find a collapsed tunnel keep wandering around, the dungeon is very linear and tunnels/passages should always be available.

[Map of the first area](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/File:SR-Map-Bleak_Falls_Barrow-Temple.png)

[Map of the second area](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/File:SR-Map-Bleak_Falls_Barrow-Sanctum.png)

Comment: [map of the first area](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/File:SR-Map-Bleak_Falls_Barrow-Temple.png) of Bleak Falls Barrow. was going to add it as a comment to the question but i'll give it to you for your answer

Comment: and the [map of the second area](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/File:SR-Map-Bleak_Falls_Barrow-Sanctum.png)